# Object doesn't support property or method 'getAttribute'

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I looked at some answers but nothing worked for me and I am lost. I'm using Cordova, Ionic and Angular 2.

Here is my HTML

```
 <ion-col *ngFor="let value of myButtonsFirstRow" width-25>
  <button #elem ptcolor (click)="volumeClick(elem)" attr.floatValue="{{value}}">
    {{value | fraction}}
  </button>
</ion-col>
```

Here is my TypeScript

```
volumeClick(htmlElem: HTMLElement) {
  this.volumeSelected = +htmlElem.getAttribute('floatValue'); 
}
```

I am trying to set the value from the attribute that I created (in my HTML). But looks like I can't use the getAttribute method. My htmlElem is set but I don't see the method as well so I know i'm doing something wrong but I don't know what!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's because `elem` is an Ionic component. So i see several ways to do that:

1) Unfortunately `Button` component doesn't have a public method/property to get `nativeElement`/`attribute`. This code should work:

```
volumeClick(elem: any) {
    this.volumeSelected = +elem._elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('floatValue'); 
}
```

2) Other way to get attribute is using `$event` in your template like this:

```
<button (click)="volumeClick($event)" attr.floatValue="{{value}}"> {{value}}</button>
```

Then your method will look like:

```
volumeClick(event: any) {
  this.volumeSelected = +event.currentTarget.getAttribute('floatValue'); 
}
```

NOTE: I use `currentTarget` because `Button` component have several childs.

3) You could just pass `value` to click event:

```
<button (click)="volumeClick(value)">{{value}}</button>

volumeClick(value: any) {
  this.volumeSelected = value; 
}
```

Or a bit simple:

```
<button (click)="volumeSelected = value">{{value}}</button>
```

Comment: That's what i thought, an Ionic element... even though the button element is the same as an HTML one haha. Anyway, i won't fall for that one again. Your answer #1 was perfect ! Thanks again ! :)

Answer (score 0):

The reference of a template variable returns an `ElementRef`. If you want to access the `HTMLElement` use `ElementRef.nativeElement`

```
volumeClick(htmlElem: ElementRef) {
  this.volumeSelected = +htmlElem.nativeElement.getAttribute('floatValue'); 
}
```

Comment: don't you think that `attr.floatValue` should wrap with `[]`

Comment: Either `[]` or `{{}}` but never both.

Comment: It was one of the first thing i tried. And it worked, i have access to the getAttribute method. But it's null like he doesn't get what is my attribute. Am i using the good syntax in the getAttribute ?

Comment: Oh.. I thought `{{}}` needs only `floatValue="{{value}}"`

Comment: No, the difference is that `{{}}` stringyfies the value before it assigns it, otherwise AFAIK it still needs `attr.` if there is no property (input) with this name.

Comment: I was wrong, `nativeElement` is not necessary https://plnkr.co/edit/eidk8EwdjUMWmvVGkWI2?p=preview

Comment: @PankajParkar what was your answer? If your's was correct, I'm going to delete mine. I haven't actually changed anything in the Plunker, except removing the `fraction` pipe to make the Plunker work.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer no man.. mine was wrong answer..correct your answer.. I'm ready to upvote :p

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer your plunker is exactly what i have in my question. Weird how it works with your code and doesn't in my project. Could it be because `<button>` is an Ionic element ? i might be wrong..

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about Ionic.